# Chain class methods with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine I have the following simplified class:

```py
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self, input_1):
        self.input_1 = input_1

    def method_1(self):
        # Do something
        return self

    def method_2(self):
        # Do something
        return self

    def method_3(self):
        # Do something
        return self

instance = ExampleClass('Hello')
```

If I wanted to call the methods sequentially, I could simply chain them as such:

```py
instance \
    .method_1() \
    .method_2() \
    .method_3()
```

Now imagine I also have a condition, that if evaluates to true, should call `method_2()`, otherwise call `method_3()`.
I can achieve this by writing:

```py
dummy_condition = True

instance.method_1()

if dummy_condition:
    instance.method_2()
else:
    instance.method_3()
```

**Question:** How can I perform this logic without so much verbose code, using method chaining instead? I have tried being creative, and came up with the following, which unfortunately doesn't work:

```py
instance \
    .method_1() \
    (.method_2() if dummy_condition else .method_3())
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this instead:

```py
instance.method_1().__getattribute__("method_2" if dummy_condition else "method_3")()
```

This utilises `__getattribute__` dunder then calls it

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `__getattribute__` magic method. You are able to get an attribute of your instance based on name (str) of its.

**`__getattribute__`:**

> Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances
> of the class. If the class also defines **getattr**(), the latter will
> not be called unless **getattribute**() either calls it explicitly or
> raises an AttributeError. This method should return the (computed)
> attribute value or raise an AttributeError exception. In order to
> avoid infinite recursion in this method, its implementation should
> always call the base class method with the same name to access any
> attributes it needs, for example, object.**getattribute**(self, name).

**Reference:**

- https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#more-attribute-access-for-new-style-classes

**Code:**

```
class ExampleClass:
    def __init__(self, input_1):
        self.input_1 = input_1

    def method_1(self):
        print("METHOD_1")
        return self

    def method_2(self):
        print("METHOD_2")
        return self

    def method_3(self):
        print("METHOD_3")
        return self


instance = ExampleClass("Hello")

dummy_condition = True

instance.method_1().__getattribute__("method_2" if dummy_condition else "method_3")()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
METHOD_1
METHOD_2
```

**Output if `dummy_condition = False`:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
METHOD_1
METHOD_3
```